# Android Studio - how to import app with libraries as a library?

Tags: android, import, android-studio

I would like to import an application which has several libraries as a library itself into a different app in Android Studio.

My question is - is it simply a matter of copying the app (including it's libraries) into my project, then taking the following steps:

1) Modifying the imported app's build.gradle file to type of plugin from "app" to "library", i.e. `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`

2) changing app project's settings.gradle to include the (converted) app and it's libraries

e.g.

```
include ':myapp', ':otherapp',:lib1', ':lib2', ':lib3', ':lib4'
```

I feel like I may be better off importing the libraries into my own app, and then copying what I need from from the other app as part of my app.

Also, is copying a better idea than using the "import module" functionality? That led to problems, regarding jar conflicts...were supported, not supported etc. I may run into those again, come to think of it.

Comment: Talking about convenience, it's much easier to pack your library into one or several .aar archives and use them wherever you want, rather than taking your importing the whole folder each time with associated potential importing problems. If you still prefer the second option, you will also need to add a dependency to your "user" module: `compile project(":lib1");...`

Comment: You add those libraries to your app's `build.gradle`.